# I get an IOException when building the Roofline Tool. Why?

Tags: gradle

I currently get the error below trying to run roofline. It would be nice if any of you could help me out getting this up and running in my new environment?

bravegag@bravegag-MacBookPro:/opt/roofline/tool$ ./gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open task artifact state cache (/opt/roofline/tool/.gradle/1.0-milestone-8/taskArtifacts).

> java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
>   
>   BUILD FAILED

==> You have to have write access for the directory you are trying to build in.

Comment: Are permissions correct? What does `ls -all /opt/roofline/tool/.gradle/1.0-milestone-8/taskArtifacts` output? And for `/opt/roofline/tool`?

Comment: Can you add a link to whatever roofline is so people can try to reproduce that error?

Comment: Can be found at https://github.com/GeorgOfenbeck/roofline (Check the Wiki there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have write access for the directory you are trying to build in